# Acoustic Response of Tube with Liquid Around It

Tags: acoustics, frequency

Speaking generally, is it possible to measure the height of a fluid surrounding a tube by emitting a frequency from a speaker at the top of the tube, and reading the response using a microphone at the bottom?

Is there a more efficient way of measuring height acoustically?

I understand the generality of the question, just looking for ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. I'll draw the tube horizontally for convenience:

[image: Tube]

Suppose the velocity of the sound in air is $v_a$ and the velocity in the fluid is $_f$, then the travel time, $t$, for the sound wave is:

$$ t = \frac{d-x}{v_a} + \frac{x}{v_f} $$

which rearranges to:

$$ x = \frac{v_fv_a}{v_f - v_a}\left(\frac{d}{v_a} - t\right) $$

So by measuring the travel time of the sound, $t$, you can calculate the height of the liquid, $x$.

What problems you'd run into in practice I'm afraid I don't know.